# Spring Webservices Adding Elements to Soap Request

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

In my java project, I am using Spring Webservices to send an xml message to an endpoint that my vendor has supplied. (They asked us to do it this way )

However I noticed 1 of my requests was failing. On further analysis by posting the request to request bin -  I noticed that certain elements were being adding to my soap message with the prefix of SOAP-ENV

My question is - is it possible to use spring webservices but not have these extra elements added to my soap message

**Code To Call Webservice**

public void callWebservice(String corpId) {

```
StringBuilder soapMessage = FileUtil.readFileContent(BASE_TALEO_CONFIG_LOCATION + "/CallWebservice.xml");

StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(soapMessage.toString()));
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);

boolean webserviceResult = webServiceTemplate.getWebServiceTemplate().sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(baseURL, source, result);
System.out.println("webserviceResult:" + webserviceResult);
```

}

**XML Message I want to send**

```
 <retrieve:retrieveEntities xmlns:retrieve="http://www.test/2009/04/retrieve">
  <retrieve:mappingVersion>http://www.test.com/2009/04</retrieve:mappingVersion>
  <retrieve:query>    
  </retrieve:query>
  <retrieve:attributes />
</retrieve:retrieveEntities>
```

**Message in Request Bin**

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<retrieve:retrieveEntities xmlns:retrieve="http://www.test/2009/04/retrieve"><retrieve:mappingVersion>http://www.test.com/2009/04</retrieve:mappingVersion><retrieve:query/>
<retrieve:attributes/>
</retrieve:retrieveEntities>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Thanks
Damien

Comment: The whole point of SOAP is that the soap envelope and header are added. If you remove the SOAP part you don't have a soap web service anymore.

Comment: I completely understand your point but unfortunately the vendor doesnt support the envelope and header like this

Comment: Then it isn't a SOAP web service, then don't send it as SOAP. Configure your web service template to use the `DomPoxMessageFactory` instead of a `SoapMessageFactory` (which is the default).

Comment: that did the trick - cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web service you are calling isn't a SOAP web service but a plain XML based web service. By default the `WebServiceTemplate` assumes that you are sending SOAP messages and as such creates a [`SaajSoapMessageFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/soap/SoapMessageFactory.html).

If you don't want to send SOAP messages you need to configure the `WebServiceTemplate` to send plain XML messages. For this add the [`DomPoxMessageFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/pox/dom/DomPoxMessageFactory.html) as message factory to the `WebServiceTemplate`. (Judging on the code you are using the `WebServiceGateway` base class.

```
<bean id="yourGateway" class="your class">
    <property name="messageFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.pox.dom.DomPoxMessageFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

See also [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html#d5e1802) of the reference guide.